# Guide to writing specs in Erlang

Tags: types, erlang, specs

In open source projects I see the following two ways of writing specs:

Specs in comments

```
@spec start_link() -> {ok, pid()}
```

Specs in source code

```
-spec start_link() -> {ok, pid()}
```

What's the difference? Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comment (`@spec`) version predates the source code (`-spec`) version.  The latter is preferable.

according to [EDoc documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/chapter.html#Type_specifications):

> Note: Although the syntax described in the following can still be used
>   for specifying functions we recommend that Erlang specifications as
>   described in [Types and Function Specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) should be added to the
>   source code instead. This way the analyses of Dialyzer's can be
>   utilized in the process of keeping the documentation consistent and
>   up-to-date. Erlang specifications will be used unless there is also a
>   function specification (a @spec tag followed by a type) with the same
>   name.